# Coin counting machines in UK bank branches

Tags: united-kingdom, cash, coins

A colleague recently mentioned to me that many HSBC branches offer self-service [coin counting machines](http://www.hsbc.co.uk/1/2/contact-and-support/ways-to-bank/branch-banking/self-service-banking) - you tip a bag of loose change in, and it credits it to your account. No need to queue up and annoy the counter staff with a bagful of small coins, which I can imagine they hate.

This struck me as a great idea - these machines are common in supermarkets etc, but they tend to take an 8-10% commission, which feels unreasonably high. (though see [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/4007/how-do-you-get-rid-of-your-spare-change) for a different perspective)

Unfortunately, I don't have an HSBC account. Do any *other* UK banks offer these, either as a routine thing or in specific branches?

Comment: Ask your bank. They're fairly common in the US but not universal, and my bank doesn't charge for the service if you're depositing that coinage.

Comment: Natwest /RBS seems to have them in some branches I saw on being used last week

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Metro Bank](https://www.metrobankonline.co.uk/Discover-Metro-Bank/More-Convenient-Services/Magic-Money-Machine/) has coin counting machines in all of their branches. You don't even need to be a customer, just hand over the slip you get at the counter, and you'll get cash. Plus, if you guess the amount of coins to the nearest pound, you get a free prize (a branded yoyo/water bottle/etc.)!

NatWest has a few in their branches too (mainly larger ones), but you need an account.

Neither of these two banks charge.

Comment: Oh, great! There's one here in Cambridge which I go past frequently. Will drop in and take a look.

Comment: As at 09.01.2022: You now need a Metro Bank account to use theur coin machines. Yet another Covid hurdle!